# Как воспроизводить аудио в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, аудио, qmediaplayer

Я пробовал несколько вариантов воспроизведения аудио в *PyQt5*, но они не работали.

Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                               # !!!
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                    # !!!
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png").scaled(400, 400)      # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(800)       
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        else:    
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)            
        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(420, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы пишите что пробовал несколько вариантов, пожалуйста, покажите хоть что-то что вы пробовали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QMediaPlayer` позволяет воспроизводить медиа источник.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html

Просто скопируйте мой пример, кликните по кнопке и слушайте, и наслаждайтесь.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                               
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                    
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png").scaled(400, 400)          # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)  

        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self)                              # !!!
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(                      # !!!
            'http://europaplus.hostingradio.ru:8014/ep-top256.mp3'    # !!!
        )))                                                           # !!!
        self.player.setVolume(80) 
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
            self.player.stop()                                            # !!!
        else:    
            self.player.play()                                            # !!!
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)            
        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(420, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена, вот решение:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    filename = 'music.mp3'
    fullpath = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(filename) 
    url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)
    content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url)
    player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
    player.setMedia(content)
    player.play()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```